# Modifying default input form for Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, powerapp

I have a Sharepoint list that I am modifying, and my customers like the default input form (image below) but are requesting I add a few fields to this/make minor formatting changes to it.  They do not want the layout of a customized form in Power Apps. My question(s) are:

1. Is it possible to modify the below input form with a few additional fields (that are already found in my list but not currently displayed in the form)?  If not...
2. Is there a way I can use Power Apps to modify the default form layout below, adding the fields that I'm looking to add?

I'm new to maintaining Sharepoint lists and using Power Apps, so a simple solution is preferred here, if at all possible.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Display hidden columns in your form**

If you are sure that the columns already exist in your list, then you can make sure they show up in the form by doing the following:

- Navigate to the list settings
- Click Advanced settings

[image]

- Make sure the **Allow management of content types?** is set to **Yes**

[image]

- In the list settings, click on the content type. For example, Item:

[image]

- Click on the field name you want to display on your form. For example, **Names**:

[image]

- Now make sure the field is either **Required** or **Optional**. If you want to keep a field **Hidden** - select **Hidden**

[image]

**Modifying the form using Power Apps**

Since your form is very simple, there is no harm trying to use a Power App form as a proof of concept. In order to try it:

- Navigate to the list settings
- Click **Form settings**

[image]

- Click Customize in PowerApps

[image]

- Save and **Publish!** your new Power App form

If you don't like your new Power App form, you can always switch back to using the default SharePoint form by going to the list settings > forms > Use the default SharePoint form:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Denis.  My field is indeed set to 'Optional', however does not show up in the default Sharepoint form.  My problem is that I'm unable to modify this default Sharepoint form in Power Apps, and must use the custom form as an input (which my users do not like), if I wish to add/remove fields from it.  Is my understanding correct?  Am I not able to modify the default Sharepoint form via Power Apps?

Answer (score 0):

**Display columns in Edit Form**

1.Go to **List settings** >> **Advanced settings** >> enable "**Allow management of content types**"

[image]

2.On the List Settings page, scroll to **the Content Types section**. And then, click on **Item**.

3.On the List Content Type, scroll to **the Columns section**. Make sure the status of column is **Optional** or **Required**.

[image]

**Modify the Edit Form using Power Apps**

1.Go to **List settings** >> **Form settings**

2.On the Form Settings page, click on "**Customize in PowerApps**"

[image]

3.The page will go to the Power Apps interface, and then you can select the field you want to edit to set the font style.

[image]

More information about Customize list or library form by using Power Apps, please refer to **[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)**.

============================== **Updated Answer** ==============================

Yes, your understanding is correct.

When you modify the custom form in Power Apps, the following situation will appear on the Form Setting page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  However, modifying in Power Apps means you are modifying the customized form and not the default Sharepoint form - do I understand this correctly?  i.e. I'm not able to modify the default Sharepoint form and add fields from my list accordingly?

Comment: Hi, user96941. Thanks for your reply. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!